# Где найти все команды стандартной библиотеки Java с описанием?

Tags: java, android, gps

Где найти все свежие команды стандартных библиотек, методы классов, связанных с работой GPS в Android 6.0 на Java в Android Studio (Включая список возможных команд permission)?
Вопрос ко всем библиотекам JAVA относится, но столкнулся конкретно в работе с GPS. Ведь если есть библиотека, должно же быть описание к ней где-то.
Также не могу найти в Android Studio функцию, что-то вроде Show Javadoc в NetBeans, по нажатию там правой кнопки на интересующую команду отправлят на сайт с полным списком команд (на котором нет нужных классов для Android, таких как LocationListener). Должно же быть в Android Studio что-то, кроме Find Sample Code, который даёт мало информативную ссылку на сайт Android Developers.

К примеру:
Для файла MainActiviy.java...:

```
package com.example.shmko.getcoords;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    Button button;
    private static TextView LatGPS;
    private static TextView LonGPS;
    private TextView LatProvaider;
    private TextView LonProvaider;
    private double x=0, y=0, px=0, py=0;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        LatGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        LonGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        LatProvaider = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        LonProvaider = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LatGPS.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                LonGPS.setText(String.valueOf(y));
                LatProvaider.setText(String.valueOf(px));
                LonProvaider.setText(String.valueOf(py));
            }
        });

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10,
                this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        x=location.getLatitude();
        y=location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
```

...необходимо добавить в 52 строчке явный доступ к GPS модулю с разрешения пользователя при каждом запуске.
Где найти команду, открывающую доступ?
Так-же нужно найти команду для получения широты, долготы от провайдера (78 строка). И возможно больше команд (чтобы использовать координаты провайдера для ускорения холодного старта GPS модуля).

Файл манифеста AndroidManifest.xml(так-же интересуют возможные команды):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shmko.getcoords">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

Файл пользовательского интерфейса activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shmko.getcoords.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Lat"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Lon"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Широта"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Долгота"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="GPS"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Провайдер"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Lat"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Lon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Широта"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Долгота"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Получить координаты"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: Попробуйте <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> по методу.

Comment: Ctrl+Q - открывает quick-doc, Shift+F1 - документацию в браузере, для выражения, на котором находится курсор

Comment: Вы не путайте стандартные библиотеки `Java` с андроидными библиотеками. `java` к одному андроиду не сводится. Стандартные библиотеки `java` описаны на сайте  *Oracle* . Учебник: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html, справочник: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: И зря вы так много кода постите, тем более что все равно никто его читать не будет, так как к сути вопроса он не имеет никакого отношения.